# SSIS/WinSCP - Upgrading WinSCP on prod and not breaking SSIS packages

Tags: ssis, winscp

We are using WinSCP within SSIS packages to FTPS and SFTP files to various locations. Our packagers are set up with TFS auto-deploy (albeit manual configuration) and so far, everything is working great (at least through DV, QA, and UA environments).

The packages currently have version **5.13.1** set as a reference, which is the version of WinSCP that is GAC’d on the DV, QA, and UA servers (as well as the version of the EXE).

However, when discussing our prod locations with our network architect, he insists the version of WinSCP that exists in the prod environments must be the latest, stable version.

- How can I create my packages in a way that allows them to work, even when the server version of WinSCP has been upgraded?

We can set parameters for configuration as needed.

Comment: Isn't WinSCP used in an "Execute Process" task that only depends on the **location** of the executable? Why should the version be important?

Comment: I'm using within a script task, which is the recommended approach. When the version that is GAC'd does not align with the reference in the package, I always receive an invocation error.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP can be executed from SSIS in two ways that I am currently aware of:

1. Execute Process Task
2. Script Task using the WinSCPnet.dll

When you say that you have "GAC'd" WinSCP then that tells me you are using the second method listed above. The version of WinSCP should not matter as long as the application and DLL file are in-line. You should only be concerned if features have been removed in newer versions, which I doubt is the case.

You should install the newer version in the lower environments to ensure that it works. There is no substitute for testing in the lower environments, unless you are that guy from the Dos Equis commercials who admires the virtues of Testing In Production (TIP):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seliot/2011/04/25/i-dont-always-test-my-code-but-when-i-do-i-do-it-in-production/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. After testing on my machine, it appears that you are correct. So, to reiterate, it doesn't matter what version that the EXE is as long as the assembly utilized as the package reference and what is GAC'd are in line.

Comment: You might want to consider marking this as answered so other users will know.